# Deploy JSF EAR on weblogic in openshift

Tags: primefaces, openshift, weblogic, jsf-2.2, kubernetes-operator

We have JSF/Primefaces app built and deployed as EAR on Weblogic 12c. It connects to Oracle 19c DB. We are required to lift and shift this application to openshift environment. https://blogs.oracle.com/weblogicserver/post/running-weblogic-on-openshift seems to have instructions to deploy weblogic app to openshift but not sure if there is anything more to be done for JSP/Primeface based apps.

Please help advise on the steps needed for this. Are there any known limitations or issues?